# Why do I need rotateX to make :after :before tooltips work?

Tags: css

I have a table with tool tips invoked from tr:hover and tr:action using :after and :before.
JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/00a3u73p/4/)

EDIT:
If I don't have the position: relative in the td or the rotateX(0) in tr:hover td  the tooltips no longer appear...
Why is this required?

CSS

```
/*Striped background to show transparency */
body{
        background-image: linear-gradient(black 10%, transparent 10%);
        background-size: auto 10px;
}
/*Base format*/
table {
    float: left;
    table-layout: auto;
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 1px 0;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: default;
}
td {

    /*Fix 1 ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????*/
    position: relative;
    /*???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????*/

    /*Dynamic elements*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0033CC, #FFFFDB);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Header*/
    th {
        padding-left: 1%; /*not inherited from table*/
        width: 50%;
        color: #FFFF66;
        background-color: #0000CC;
    }
    tr:active th {
        opacity: 0.5;
        color: red;
    }

/* Tool tip base*/
    /*body*/
    tr:hover td:last-child:after, tr:active td:last-child:after {
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: absolute;
        left: calc(100% + 6px);
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: black;
    }
    /*pointer*/
    tr:hover td:last-child:before, tr:active td:last-child:before{
        /*make a little arrow beside the tool tip */
        content: '';
        border: solid;
        width: 0; height: 0;
        border-color: transparent #cacae1 transparent transparent;
        border-width: 6px 6px 6px 0;
        bottom: calc(50% - 6px);
        left: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }

/*Row hover*/
    tr:hover td {
        /*transform background gradient*/
        background: linear-gradient(to top,#4D70DB,#FFFF00);
        /*transform opacity for the element*/
        opacity: 0.8;

        /*Fix 2 ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????*/
        transform: rotateX(0);
        /*???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????*/
    }
    /* adjust tool tip */
    tr:hover td:last-child:after {
        content: 'Click to SELECT';
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #FFFF00;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#4D70DB,#FFFF00);
    }

/*Row select*/
    tr:active td {
        opacity: 1.0;
        color: red;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#4D70DB,#FF8585);
    }
    /* adjust tool tip */
    tr:active td:last-child:after {
        content: 'SELECTED';
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#4D70DB,#FF8585);
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px red;
        color: red;
    }
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <table border="0" width="75%" draggable="false">
        <tr id="header">
            <th><b>COL1</b></th>
            <th><b>COL2</b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow.  There's a lot more css in the fiddle than in your example

Comment: @graphicdivine I figured it would clutter up the post... should I include it here? It seems redundant...

Comment: Probably because otherwise it is not clear what the absolute positioning should take as reference point … switching the rotation for `position:relative` on the `td` seems to fix it, at least in Chrome (but in older Firefoxes it might be problematic).

Comment: Ok, after I understand where the problem is I'll include the  relevant code here. Meanwhile, the context is fully established in the fiddle.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, your suggestion works but I don't understand why.  Surely there is a default context for the reference point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an element is [positioned absolutely](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning), it is positioned in relation to its [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block), (generally its nearest positioned ancestor).  Applying certain values of `transform` [create a new containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#module-interactions).

This is why (as mentioned in the comments) replacing the transform with `position: relative` has the same effect.  It too creates a containing block, causing your absolute element to position in relation to it.

Using a relatively positioned ancestor is a much more standard practice than applying an unneeded transform when needing to create a new containing block.  I suggest you replace your transform with `position: relative`.

Comment: Thanks, very nice answer.  I ran across a similar problem when trying to absolutely position one span in a transformed li. I need to allow the first span to float left, regardless of the list indenting, so I established positioning in the container and positioned the span absolute. But the transform on the li broke it for the same reason you describe.